# Conditionally Import Shared module using static method forRoot

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-modules

I have angular application divided into various modules on the basis of user type. Like `AdminModule`, `CustomerModule`, `VendorMoudle` etc. For each modules I've a separate respective shared module, having all the reusable items (components, pipes, directive etc). Like `AdminSharedModule`, `CustomerSharedModule` and `VendorSharedModule`.

Along with each shared modules I've various featured modules inside each user level module which imports the respective user's shared module. For example, all featured modules of `AdminModule` will import `AdminShared` module. Similarly, all featured modules of Customer will import `CustomerSharedModule`.

Now, I've a situation that there are some featured modules that belong to more than one user's module. Suppose, I've a featured module called `CommonFeatureModule`. Now, I can create this module anywhere in the application & can call it lazily through routing in any of the module.

Now, here is the problem. As I explained, inside each featured module, I've imported the related User's Shared module. But for `CommonFeatureModule` I've to conditionally import shared modules. Like if the `CommonFeatureModule` is loaded through `AdminModule` then the `CommonFeatureModule` should import `AdminSharedModule`. But if the `CommonFeatureModule` is loaded in `CustomerModule` then the `CommonFeatureModule` should import `CustomerSharedModule`.

I've tried creating a module called `SharedModule` & inside this module I've used the static method `forRoot` to conditionally load the respective user's shared module. But this solution didn't work. Her is the code for my `SharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SharedComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: []
})
export class SharedComponent{
    static forRoot(user: UserService): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
        const data = {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            imports: [
                user.isAdminUser() ? AdminSharedModule : CustomerSharedModule
            ],
            exports: [
                user.isAdminUser ? AdminSharedModule : CustomerSharedModule
            ]
        };

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: forRoot is not made for this purpose. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services 
could  you share more infos about your application structure? How do you use this modules?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to know. I've already explained the whole application structure. You can consider it the way as I've a module and instead of a static object,  I want to pass a dynamic object to the NgModule decorator of that module. In other words, instead of a predefined object, I want to build object on the basis of certain conditions. So, I want to know, is there anyway we can create the input object of NgModule decorator on the basis of certain conditions.

Comment: As far as I know dynamic rendering is the most fit option for your application structure. Even with your detailed exmplaination, I am still missing the full picture of your code. It would be best if you could share the code of all that involved parts of your application to get a better answer. The best is to make a tiny stackblitz example of your app.